# org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException at Build and deploy

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, eofexception

I'm trying to develop the samples but sometimes when I build and deploy an apps the process fails, and at eclipse Worklight Console appears:

```
14-feb-2013 16:28:55 com.worklight.report.impl.GadgetReportsServiceImpl loadProperties
INFO: FWLSE3005I: Application raw reports are disabled.
14-feb-2013 16:28:55 com.worklight.server.bundle.project.ProjectBundleManager doStart
INFO: FWLST0010I: ====== Started server for project module_22_0_CustomLoginModule-project-customization; Worklight version=5.0.5.20130115-0926-developer-edition
14-feb-2013 16:32:25 org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher 
GRAVE: Failed executing POST /applications/upload
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: timeout
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.messagebody.ReaderUtility.doRead(ReaderUtility.java:123)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.messagebody.ReaderUtility.doRead(ReaderUtility.java:93)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:146)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:114)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:252)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:217)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:206)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:503)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:480)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:207)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:38)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:143)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:64)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:954)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: timeout
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.blockForContent(HttpParser.java:1186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.read(HttpInput.java:57)
    at java.io.SequenceInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.james.mime4j.io.BufferedLineReaderInputStream.fillBuffer(BufferedLineReaderInputStream.java:94)
    at org.apache.james.mime4j.io.MimeBoundaryInputStream.fillBuffer(MimeBoundaryInputStream.java:196)
    at org.apache.james.mime4j.io.MimeBoundaryInputStream.read(MimeBoundaryInputStream.java:127)
    at org.apache.james.mime4j.io.BufferedLineReaderInputStream.fillBuffer(BufferedLineReaderInputStream.java:94)
    at org.apache.james.mime4j.io.BufferedLineReaderInputStream.read(BufferedLineReaderInputStream.java:137)
    at org.apache.james.mime4j.io.LineReaderInputStreamAdaptor.read(LineReaderInputStreamAdaptor.java:67)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.james.mime4j.codec.CodecUtil.copy(CodecUtil.java:42)
    at org.apache.james.mime4j.storage.AbstractStorageProvider.store(AbstractStorageProvider.java:57)
    at org.apache.james.mime4j.message.BodyFactory.binaryBody(BodyFactory.java:92)
    at org.apache.james.mime4j.message.MessageBuilder.body(MessageBuilder.java:150)
    at org.apache.james.mime4j.parser.MimeStreamParser.parse(MimeStreamParser.java:101)
    at org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Message.<init>(Message.java:141)
    at org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Message.<init>(Message.java:100)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl.parse(MultipartInputImpl.java:76)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartReader.readFrom(MultipartReader.java:50)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartReader.readFrom(MultipartReader.java:20)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.messagebody.ReaderUtility.doRead(ReaderUtility.java:111)
    ... 46 more
14-feb-2013 16:32:25 com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter doFilter
GRAVE: FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleFailure(SynchronousDispatcher.java:255)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleReaderException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:206)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:174)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:518)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:480)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:207)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:38)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:143)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:64)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:954)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ByteArrayISO8859Writer.writeTo(ByteArrayISO8859Writer.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:375)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:154)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:71)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleFailure(SynchronousDispatcher.java:246)
    ... 42 more
14-feb-2013 16:32:25 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler doHandle
ADVERTENCIA: /console/api/applications/upload
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleFailure(SynchronousDispatcher.java:255)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleReaderException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:206)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:174)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:518)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:480)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:207)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:38)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:143)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:64)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:954)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ByteArrayISO8859Writer.writeTo(ByteArrayISO8859Writer.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:375)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:154)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:71)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleFailure(SynchronousDispatcher.java:246)
    ... 42 more
```

Rebooting the laptop solves the problem but spends too time.

Can anyone help me to avoid this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Increase the memory size of the using min and max args

Comment: What memory size?
How i can increase it?

Comment: The user above refers to Eclipse's eclipse.ini, however there should be no need to do this operation by default.

Is this the entire log? Where from have you copied it? 
Can you check for additional information in eclipseWorkspace\WorklightServerHome\projectName\logs\server.log

Please also provide your environment details: Worklight version, Eclipse version, and any other steps you may have taken prior to the error.

Comment: Hi
It's not the entire log, there are a lot of lines, I wrote the header of the exceptions.

I will try to put the server.log

Comment: I feel like there is something wrong in cache, something that does not refresh properly... but i've deleted the WorklightServerHome, cleaned the workspace from eclipse and cleaned the java temporary files from windows control panel...

Comment: At the end it was the memory size. I only had to insert a this two lines at the eclipse.ini

`-XX:MaxPermSize=320m`
`-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true`