# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Error while building and deploying an application

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, socket-timeout-exception

I am getting below error while building an app in Worklight Studio:

```
AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server worklight is ready to run a smarter planet.
[ERROR   ] Failed executing POST /applications/upload
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket operation timed out before it could be completed
```

LOG:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket operation timed out before it could be completed
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:202)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:136)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:159)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1240)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:760)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:88)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:192)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:196)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1029)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4499)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket operation timed out before it could be completed
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl$BinaryOnlyMessageBuilder.body(MultipartInputImpl.java:140)
    at org.apache.james.mime4j.parser.MimeStreamParser.parse(MimeStreamParser.java:101)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl$BinaryMessage.<init>(MultipartInputImpl.java:153)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl$BinaryMessage.<init>(MultipartInputImpl.java:146)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl.parse(MultipartInputImpl.java:197)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartReader.readFrom(MultipartReader.java:50)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartReader.readFrom(MultipartReader.java:20)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:169)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket operation timed out before it could be completed
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.SocketRWChannelSelector.checkForTimeouts(SocketRWChannelSelector.java:415)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.ChannelSelector.run(ChannelSelector.java:226)
    ... 1 more

[11/14/13 11:33:38:370 GMT+05:30] 0000003f org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher                E Failed executing POST /applications/upload
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket operation timed out before it could be completed
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:202)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:136)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:159)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1240)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:760)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:88)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:192)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:196)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1029)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4499)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket operation timed out before it could be completed
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl$BinaryOnlyMessageBuilder.body(MultipartInputImpl.java:140)
    at org.apache.james.mime4j.parser.MimeStreamParser.parse(MimeStreamParser.java:101)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl$BinaryMessage.<init>(MultipartInputImpl.java:153)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl$BinaryMessage.<init>(MultipartInputImpl.java:146)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl.parse(MultipartInputImpl.java:197)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartReader.readFrom(MultipartReader.java:50)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartReader.readFrom(MultipartReader.java:20)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:169)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket operation timed out before it could be completed
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.SocketRWChannelSelector.checkForTimeouts(SocketRWChannelSelector.java:415)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.ChannelSelector.run(ChannelSelector.java:226)
    ... 1 more
```

My system configuration is:

- MAC 10.9
- Eclipse JUNO SR2
- Java 6

Comment: This is not related to OS X 10.9, as I am using it as well with Worklight. Look at the Worklighr Development Server console log, is there any more info there about the error? Also what is your Worklight version?

Comment: Console Log "Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server: please verify that the Worklight server is started and reachable."

Comment: Worklight Version I am using is 6.0.0

Comment: There should be an exception in the Console view in Eclipse, press the down-facing arrow and choose "Worklight Development Server".

Comment: The only error I see in "Worklight Development Server" console view is what i mention in my question

[ERROR   ] Failed executing POST /applications/upload
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket operation timed out before it could be completed

server tries 3 times then says build failed 

"Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server: please verify that the Worklight server is started and reachable."

Comment: It could also be that you have a firewall that is blocking you somewhat - if you do have one, try disabling it and see if deployment passes. See my answer below.

Comment: Firewall is disabled in my machine

Answer (score 0):

See if the answer here helps: [org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException at Build and deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828769/org-eclipse-jetty-io-eofexception-at-build-and-deploy)

1. [Open the eclipse.ini](http://blog.mynumnum.com/2011/08/how-to-modify-eclipseini-settings-in.html) file and
2. Add to it the following: `X:MaxPermSize=320m -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true`

It could also be that you have a firewall that is blocking you somewhat - if you do have one, try disabling it and see if deployment passes.

Comment: Hi I also have the same error. I tried your suggestion, but it didnt workout.